# C# Storing files in .bin and then extracting them as a setup

Tags: c#, extract, archive

What I want to know how to do is Store files as a .bin and be able to extract them using an application made in C#, I have attempted to do research on this but its a bit hard when the terminology for it and what you can search is vague as all hell.

I simply want to make my own installer and be able to keep files (exe, dll, ini etc) in a either 1 or multiple .bin files and then when the program is ran the user can click on 'install' and then the program will extract the files that are stored and place them in the a desired location. I have seen it done in C++ but I can't find much on it in C#, if this is 'not possible' then could someone give me some resources for C++ or show me how?

Kindest Regards CodeX

Comment: Why not just put them in a Zip file and use the built in Compression namespace classes to parse the ZIP file, read them and write them to the destination ?

Comment: Reinventing wheels is just a waste of time - except your main focus is to develop a new installer framework.

Comment: Open a stream to a file named whatever.bin and copy as much bytes you want into it. It is basically the same as in C++, because a file can only store a sequence of bytes

Comment: Yes I want to make a fancy installer but thats because I want to make it for own application and make it look fancy and not look like every generic C# installer, I might try the ZIP